# "Changed Files" does not return old renamed files

Tags: github-actions

I want to return all changed files in my PR when running GitHub Actions:

```
      - name: Get changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v42
        with:
          include_all_old_new_renamed_files: true

      - name: List all changed files
        env:
          ALL_CHANGED_FILES: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}
        run: |
              for file in ${ALL_CHANGED_FILES}; do
                echo "$file was changed"
              done
```

I am using [`tj-actions/changed-files`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files#output_all_old_new_renamed_files) to retrieve besides the renamed files also the old name or previous name of files, using `include_all_old_new_renamed_files` but it does not help and I get only the new files name.

How to get and previous file name when editing a title?

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue on the proper [action github repository](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files) in that case explaining the behavior you observed.